# PowerShell Create Directory If Not Exists using Test-Path does not work

Tags: powershell, directory

I have a problem with my function "Do-FoldersExist" I am trying to use `test-path` to create directory folders if they do not exist, currently at runtime the returned output seems to be returning the correct folders that DO exist, but it is not creating the folders that do not exist. I haven't been able to spot the problem, I have been trying to figure out where I am going wrong for a few days now, so I am looking for help.

```
#Start Path Location Customization
$start_path = "C:\test\work\"

#Output Text File Customization
$errors = "C:\test\Error.txt"
$outliers = "C:\test\Outlier.txt"
$folderscreated = "C:\test\Created.txt"
$folderexists = "C:\test\Existing.txt"

class ListOfFolders
{
[String]$folder_name
[String]$new_folder_name
}

# $list_of_folders is the list of sub-folders to rename. Ie, when you see MANUALS, rename it to 01_Manuals. 

$list_of_folders = 
@([ListOfFolders]@{folder_name='MANUALS';new_folder_name='01_Manuals'},
[ListOfFolders]@{folder_name='SPECS';new_folder_name='02_Specs'},
[ListOfFolders]@{folder_name='PICS';new_folder_name='03_Pictures'},
[ListOfFolders]@{folder_name='PICTURES';new_folder_name='03_Pictures'},
[ListOfFolders]@{folder_name='DRAWINGS';new_folder_name='04_Drawings'},
[ListOfFolders]@{folder_name='FAILURES';new_folder_name='05_Failures'},
[ListOfFolders]@{folder_name='REPORTS';new_folder_name='06_Reports'}
)

# function Rename-Subfolders - renames folders based on the `$list_of_folders` list above. Ie, MANUALS becomes 01_Manuals

function Rename-Subfolders {
    param (
        $folder_path
    )
    
    Get-ChildItem $folder_path -Directory -Recurse |
    Foreach-Object {
        $folder_name = Split-Path -Path $_.FullName -Leaf
        $FullFileName = $_.FullName
        foreach ($folder in $list_of_folders) {
            if ($folder_name.ToUpper() -eq $folder.folder_name.ToUpper()) { 
                try {
                    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $folder.new_folder_name -ErrorAction Continue
                    }
                catch
                {
                Write-Error -Message "Unable to rename directory folder $($FullFileName). Error was:  $($_)" -ErrorAction Continue
                Echo "Unable to rename directory folder $($FullFileName). Error was:  $($_)" >> $errors
    }    
   }
  }         
 }
}

function Do-FoldersExist {
    param (
        $folder_path
    )

    Get-ChildItem $folder_path -Directory |
    Foreach-Object {
        $folder_name = Split-Path -Path $_.FullName -Leaf
        $FullFileName = $_.FullName
        foreach ($folder in $folder_path) {
            if (-not (Test-Path $list_of_folders.new_folder_name)) {
                try {
                    New-Item $list_of_folders.new_folder_name -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction Stop
                }
                catch { 
                    Write-Error -Message "Unable to create directory $($folder.new_folder_name). Error was: $($_)" -ErrorAction Continue
                }
                Write-Host "Successfuly created directory $($FullFileName)" -ForegroundColor Green
                Echo "Successfuly created directory $($FullFileName)" >> $folderscreated
                }
                else{
                    Write-Host "Directory already exists $($FullFileName)" -ForegroundColor Green
                    Echo "Directory already exists $($FullFileName)" >> $folderexists
                    }
                }
            }
        }

# function is used to find any other folders that are not being renamed for manual review. Ie, 07_PMs.

function Get-AdditionalFolders {
    param (
        $folder_path
    )

    Get-ChildItem $folder_path -Directory |
    ForEach-Object {
        $folder_name = Split-Path -Path $_.FullName -Leaf
        $FullFileName = $_.FullName
        foreach ($folder in $folder_path) { 
            if ($folder_name -notin $list_of_folders.new_folder_name) {
            Write-Host "Additional Folder Found $($folder_name)" -ForegroundColor Green
            Echo "Additional Folder Requires Attention: $($FullFileName)" >> $outliers
            }
        }
    }
}


# Starting in $start_path, find all sub-folders and process them.

Get-ChildItem $start_path -Directory |
Foreach-Object {
    # skip folders that don't match the pattern nn-nnnn
    if ($_.FullName -match '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*') {
        # The folder name matches the pattern nn-nnnn. Process it. 
        Rename-Subfolders $_.FullName
        Do-FoldersExist $_.FullName
        Get-AdditionalFolders $_.FullName
    }
    else {
        Write-Error 'Does not match pattern. Skip.'
    }
}
```

I have tried to trap the problem with further try catch statements to ensure there was not an error when performing the `if (-not (Test-Path $list_of_folders.new_folder_name))` and haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Maybe you missed the `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to get all sub-folders as expected by your comment.

Comment: Do you have permission to create folder?  Try creating folder using File Explorer to verify you have permission.   If you are an admin you have to start PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin, otherwise you will just get normal user permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few compounding issues.

First, `$list_of_folders` is an **Array** you have to **treat it like an array**. I would personally stop here, refactor your code to handle it like an array before continuing.

Since it is an array, the rest of everything else won't work as you think they will. E.g. Running:

```
Test-Path $list_of_folders.new_folder_name
```

While it can "technically" work, it doesn't tell you which *one* of the items returns `$true`, just that one of the folders exist, and hence, the following `New-Item` is also nonsensical because

```
New-Item $list_of_folders.new_folder_name -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction Stop
```

Will (because you feed it an array) will try to create *all* the folders (no matter if it already exists or not) and could error out unexpectedly in the middle if one folder *does* exist. You have to manually iterate through the array and test each case.

Second, when you test the path, you have to specify the full path. otherwise it will test the path for where you are currently sitting. e.g. even though you try to iterate through a folder:

```
PS C:\> $start_path = "C:\test\work\"
PS C:\> # Starting in $start_path, find all sub-folders and process them.

PS C:\> Get-ChildItem $start_path -Directory |
PS C:\> Foreach-Object {

... etc.
```

You don't "move" anywhere:

```
...

PS C:\> Resolve-Path $list_of_folders.new_folder_name

Path
----
C:\01_Manuals
C:\02_Specs
C:\03_Pictures
C:\03_Pictures
C:\04_Drawings
C:\05_Failures
C:\06_Reports
```

The `Get-ChildItem` and the `ForEach-Object` only iterate through items but don't actually "move" you through the directories.